# Display symfony2 pages in raw PHP

Tags: php, iframe, symfony, migration

I'm having a problem with migration, raw php to Symfony2.
As it seems quite large application I've decided to partially migrate to SF2.
I'm trying to include SF2 pages in my Raw PHP.

More like partials in SF1. But the main skeleton is in Raw PHP.

I could achieve this only with iframe.

Can you please suggest any workaround?

Comment: You should have a look at theses slides about migrating a legacy php application to symfony2 : http://www.slideshare.net/fabrice.bernhard/modernisation-of-legacy-php-applications

Comment: Are you using twig? twig has an include function. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html